# Dynamic grid subset bounds

Tags: geoserver, mapbox

I have two instances of Geoserver running. One on a local machine (version 2.14.0) on Oracle 1.8.0_161. The other on a server (2.13.2) with Oracle  1.8.0_181.

On the server version when I look at Tile Caching in the layer it is setting the Grid subset bounds dynamically. On the local version when I fist set up the layer it is also dynamic but as soon as I save the settings it switches to fixed, as screengrab below. I want it to be dynamic, how do I configure this?

[image]

I'm trying to debug an error which I think is caused by the Grid set not being dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, going back to 2.13 on the local copy resolved the problem